# Find $f'$ and state the domains of $f$ and $f'$ for the function $f(x) = x^2sec^23x$.

Tags: calculus

Find $f'$ and state the domains of $f$ and $f'$.

$$f(x) = x^2sec^23x$$

$$f' = (2x)(sec^23x) + (x^2)(2sec(3x) * sec3xtan3x * 3)$$
$$f' = (2x)(sec^23x) + (x^2)(6sec(3x) * sec3xtan3x)$$

The problem I'm having is how to find the domains.

Comment: The domain would be the set in which the function is defined. (So look for the values of x where the function doesn't exist and you must exclude them from your domain). For example, the domain of 1/x can be written as $x \neq 0$ (assuming this is first-year calculus). Recall the definition of secx = 1/cosx and tanx=sinx/cosx. You can't divide by zero, so what values of x would give you cosx = 0?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: It is easier to do some simplification so you can figure out where division by zero occurs.

We have:

$$\sec^2(3x) = \dfrac{2}{\cos(6x) + 1}$$

So:

$$f(x) = \dfrac{2~x^2}{\cos(6x) + 1}$$

Now, can you determine the general result that makes the denominator a problem and then see how it applies to your original? It also makes it easier to use this for the derivative too.

One other thing that typically helps is to plot the function and derivative in order to see that there are problem areas.

Comment: Deserves an UV! +1

Comment: @amWhy: Not sure what happened to the OP or if they got it. Hope you are having a great day and thx for the support!